# How do I slide the cursor to a specific point on the screen, instead of having the cursor jump by using Robot.mouseMove()?

Tags: java, mouse, keyevent

I would like to have the cursor slide across the screen using java.  I am aware of the Robot.mouseMove(); however, this does not get the job done because that command makes the cursor jump.  I need the cursor to slide. The reason I need to get the cursor to slide is because I am trying to access the inspect element of google.  By using CTRL + SHIFT + C, I can pull up a specific point in the HTML code of the website; however, I need the cursor to slide over by two pixels.  I tried using the mouseMove(), but that didn't work.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.event.MenuKeyEvent;
public class SpeedTypeBot {
static Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
//static String text = scanner1.nextLine();
static ArrayList<String> Arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(338, 389);
    
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);   Thread.sleep(100);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);   Thread.sleep(100);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);   Thread.sleep(100);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);   Thread.sleep(100);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);   Thread.sleep(100);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);   Thread.sleep(100);
    
    r.mouseMove(61, 389);   Thread.sleep(100);
    r.mouseMove(59, 389);   Thread.sleep(100);
```

Thanks!
(I am a beginner coder; someone pls help)

Comment: Use some kind of timer, update the position via some kind of small delta until you reach the desired location

Comment: But wouldn't that also just be having the mouse jump but in very small increments?

Comment: That’s the only thing it can do. The x and y coordinates are discrete integers. If you need to, you can move it one pixel at a time.

Comment: Yes, which is basically what you're asking - remember, animation is an illusion of change over time.  The general answer to your question is, no, there is no inbuilt API which will do this, you will need to do it manually yourself